# Does javascript sort() have any side effect?

Tags: javascript, sorting

```js
function comp(arr1, arr2){
    let arr = [];
    
    for (const i of arr1) {
        arr.push(i*i);
    }
    arr1 = arr;
    return arr1.sort().toString() === arr2.sort().toString();
}
console.log(comp([2,4,5],[25,16,4]));//true
```

The above code returns true if the two arrays have same elements irrespective of how the appear. But when I run it against the test case provided on codewar it keeps returning this after passing all other test.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of null
>   What am missing?

Comment: Sort sorts on the same array object.

Comment: @Homer Don't correct typos in code. They may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: codewar  ?? , add those test cases here if available

Comment: I am sorting same array. Typos? could you please show me where it is. And the test cases are not available to me. I just want to know if there is instance where sort() returns any unusual value.

Comment: @Joyceobi your are missing the closing `]` after your second array in the last line.

Comment: I have corrected the typos but the problem is not solved. Thanks

Comment: @Turnip, I didn't think about that, thanks.

Comment: The current version of the snippet return true.  As it should be?  Btw, not that it matters, but a simple sort() doesn't sort numeric, only alphabetic.

Comment: Yes.  Later added this  < function asc(a,b){ return a - b;} > to the sort function, I am thinking of a walk around for the sort().

Comment: @Joyceobi Btw, you could golfcode it using map(). F.e. `return arr1.map(n=>n*n).sort((a,b)=>a-b).toString() === arr2.sort((a,b)=>a-b).toString()`

Comment: @LukStorms it didn't solve it but thanks all the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (arr === null || arr2 === null || arr.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
}
```

Adding the above before the return statement ensured no null value is sorted, which was the mistake I was making.
Thanks to all who contributed their ideas.